# Magento 2 Second time loading not going to observer controller_action_predispatch with cms_page_view

Tags: magento2, event-observer, theme, cache

I have created a observer **`controller_action_predispatch`** and did an echo  its triggering on all page view but with Second time loading its not triggering on **cms_page_view** for all other pages it triggers.

Dont know whats the reason, I can guess that it can be cached date, Using a weltpixel pearl theme.

How to fix this.

**events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="restrict_website" instance="Test\Dev\Model\RestrictWebsite" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**RestrictWebsite.php**

```
<?php

namespace SahiSdi\Dev\Model;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class RestrictWebsite implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * RestrictWebsite constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlFactory $urlFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->_response = $response;
        $this->_urlFactory = $urlFactory;
        $this->_context = $context;
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
        $actionFullName = strtolower($request->getFullActionName());
        echo $actionFullName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened Because of the Cache, When I disable Page Cache in admin it works, Found a alternative way to achieve my need Using customer_login.

You can also disable by cacheable="false" in block

```
<block class="Block\Class" name="blockname" cacheable="false" />
```

Doing so will slow down customer experience, So go with an alternative fix.